# Creating new folder in Test Lab HP Quality Center

Tags: python, python-2.7, hp-quality-center

I am using python to work with Quality Center and I want to create new folder automatically in Test Lab and add test tests from original folder. (I have a Development folder and would like to separate development testing from release testing)
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I found how to create new folder, but now I need to copy contents of another folder there. Create a new folder:
`newfolder = td.TestSetTreeManager.Root.AddNode("I am new folder")`

Comment: In the QC OTA API Reference, there is an example of how to copy a test case (examples of the Test Object). Maybe it helps?

Comment: @Roland There is this `ISupportCopyPaste` module in this example (and any other "copy something" example) which unfortunately doesn't exist in Python.